# Is it possible to receive messages from a parent window which is NOT the main window?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to receive a message from a button when clicked.
But instead of receiving it from the main window, I would like to receive it from a tab control, which is a child of the main window. But I'm not sure how to go about this.

This is the creation of the button:

```
deAll = CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", "Disable All", WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 135, 49, 95, 26, tabs, (HMENU)204, instance, NULL);
```

Obviously, tabs is a tab control.

This is the creation of the tab control:

```
tabs = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_TABCONTROL, 0, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 0, 0, rc.right + 2, rc.bottom - 22, hwnd, NULL, instance, NULL);
```

And hwnd is the main window.

Any ideas? Or do I have to make every control a child of the main window?
This was made using the Win32 API in C++.

Comment: Your very-first sentence is contradictory. "I'm trying to receive a message *from a button when clicked*. But instead of receiving it *from the main window*..." Which is it? From the control or from the main window? It appears you're talking about control *notifications* sent to your main window handle on behalf of a child control. Further, the subject of parent-child hierarchy seems to have little to do with what you're asking, which seems to be "how to I receive notifications from a tab-strip control?"

Comment: I probably worded that wrong. When I would click the button, it would send the message, but I would like to receive it using the tab control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tabs` window is the parent window of the button, so the button will send a `WM_COMMAND/BN_CLICKED` notification to the `tabs` window when the button is clicked.  You will have to subclass the `tabs` window via either `SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)` or `SetWindowSubClass()` to receive that message.  For example:

```
WNDPROC prevWndProc;

LRESULT CALLBACK myWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((uMsg == WM_COMMAND) && (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED))
    {
        // LOWORD(wParam) is the ID, and lParam is the HWND,
        // of the button that was clicked. do something ...
    }

    return CallWindowProc(prevWndProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

```
tabs = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_TABCONTROL, 0, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 0, 0, rc.right + 2, rc.bottom - 22, hwnd, NULL, instance, NULL);
prevWndProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(tabs, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR) &myWndProc);
```

Or:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK mySubClassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if ((uMsg == WM_COMMAND) && (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED))
    {
        // LOWORD(wParam) is the ID, and lParam is the HWND,
        // of the button that was clicked. do something ...
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

```
tabs = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_TABCONTROL, 0, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, 0, 0, rc.right + 2, rc.bottom - 22, hwnd, NULL, instance, NULL);
SetWindowSubclass(tabs, &mySubClassProc, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If a control is a child of a tab (or any other control) then it's the tab that will get notification messages like `WM_COMMAND`.

It's easiest to make your controls all children of your main window and just fix the z-order to make them appear in front of the tab (you already have `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` set on the tab control, which you would also need). If you leave the controls as children of the tab then the only way to get notification messages is to sub-class the tab.

Or, you can do this the way property sheets do it, and use child dialogs (a dialog with the `DS_CONTROL` style set) to host the tab content. Then you can have a separate dialog procedure that handles messages from the child controls, and it makes it easy to show/hide a whole page of controls rather than handling them all individually. The `TCM_ADJUSTRECT` message can be used to calculate the size/position that you need to display your child dialog at.

Comment: +1 Also Note that child controls of the Common Controls ilk (tab strip, listview, treeview, spinners, etc) send their notifications to their respective parent window via the WM_NOTIFY and NMHDR info. The concept, however, is largely the same.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, I'll find it useful as I get better. However I am curious on what WS_CLIPSIBLINGS specifically does. I get the general idea, but is there anything underneath that...?

Comment: `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` stops a control drawing over the top of other controls that it intersects with.